# Get monthly and overall averages of two variables from netcdf layer, for many years in R

Tags: r, raster, spatial, netcdf

Apologies in advance, I am very new to using netcdf files and imagine this is very simple but I just can't seem to crack it. I am confused between the variables, dimensions and the actual data. I would like as simple code as possible.

I have a netcdf file from Copernicus which has is structured as follows when brought into R via:
`chl <- nc_open(file)` using ncdf4 package.

So I have 2 variables - chlorophyl and net primary productivity.
4 dimensions: time, depth, latitude, longitude.

```
 2 variables (excluding dimension variables):
    float chl[longitude,latitude,depth,time]   
        long_name: Total Chlorophyll
        standard_name: mass_concentration_of_chlorophyll_a_in_sea_water
        units: mg m-3
        unit_long: milligram of Chlorophyll per cubic meter
        _FillValue: 9.96920996838687e+36
        _ChunkSizes: 1
         _ChunkSizes: 15
         _ChunkSizes: 137
         _ChunkSizes: 288
    float nppv[longitude,latitude,depth,time]   
        long_name: Total Primary Production of Phyto
        standard_name: net_primary_production_of_biomass_expressed_as_carbon_per_unit_volume_in_sea_water
        units: mg m-3 day-1
        unit_long: milligrams of Carbon per cubic meter per day
        _FillValue: 9.96920996838687e+36
        _ChunkSizes: 1
         _ChunkSizes: 15
         _ChunkSizes: 137
         _ChunkSizes: 288

 4 dimensions:
    time  Size:323
        long_name: Time (hours since 1950-01-01)
        standard_name: time
        calendar: gregorian
        units: hours since 1950-01-01 00:00:00
        axis: T
        _ChunkSizes: 1024
        _CoordinateAxisType: Time
        valid_min: 377316
        valid_max: 612503.9375
    depth  Size:1
        valid_min: 0.505760014057159
        valid_max: 0.505760014057159
        units: m
        positive: down
        unit_long: Meters
        long_name: Depth
        standard_name: depth
        axis: Z
        _ChunkSizes: 75
        _CoordinateAxisType: Height
        _CoordinateZisPositive: down
    latitude  Size:153
        valid_min: 34
        valid_max: 72
        step: 0.25
        units: degrees_north
        unit_long: Degrees North
        long_name: Latitude
        standard_name: latitude
        axis: Y
        _ChunkSizes: 681
        _CoordinateAxisType: Lat
    longitude  Size:185
        valid_min: -27
        valid_max: 19
        step: 0.25
        units: degrees_east
        unit_long: Degrees East
        long_name: Longitude
        standard_name: longitude
        axis: X
        _ChunkSizes: 1440
        _CoordinateAxisType: Lon

17 global attributes:
    product: GLOBAL_REANALYSIS_BIO_001_029
    producer: CMEMS - Global Monitoring and Forecasting Centre
    title: Monthly mean fields for product GLOBAL_REANALYSIS_BIO_001_029
    area: GLOBAL
    quality_information_document: http://marine.copernicus.eu/documents/QUID/CMEMS-GLO-QUID-001-029.pdf
    Conventions: CF-1.6
    credit: E.U. Copernicus Marine Service Information (CMEMS)
    contact: servicedesk.cmems@mercator-ocean.eu
    references: http://marine.copernicus.eu
    source: MERCATOR FREEBIORYS2V4
    licence: http://marine.copernicus.eu/services-portfolio/service-commitments-and-licence/
    dataset: global-reanalysis-bio-001-029-monthly
    institution: Mercator Ocean
    product_user_manual: http://marine.copernicus.eu/documents/PUM/CMEMS-GLO-PUM-001-029.pdf
    _CoordSysBuilder: ucar.nc2.dataset.conv.CF1Convention
    comment: 
    history: Data extracted from dataset http://localhost:8080/thredds/dodsC/global-reanalysis-bio-001-029-monthly
```

I'd like to obtain a simple code that:

1. Gets this netcdf file into a **raster stack**, one for CHL and one for PP for each month.
2. Splits each "month" (time attribute) into **yearly averages** for each.
3. Gives the **overall average** of Chl and average of PP from all the months across the whole dataset.
4. Have a line of code to include, that takes a **depth averaged mean** for CHL and PP for the above. Currently there is 1 depth level, depth  Size:1, but I can have up to 72 and would like to including taking depth average if possible in my code.**

So far... I have got this far in the code:

````
    # Opened the netcdf file
    nc <- nc_open(file) # Open file
    # Use attributes to get variable attributes
    attributes(nc)$names ```
    # Got the nc variable names
    attributes(nc$var)$names
    [1] "chl"  "nppv"
    
    #Get attributes of variables
    ncatt_get(nc, attributes(nc$var)$names[1])
    ncatt_get(nc, attributes(nc$var)$names[2])
    
    # Get  latitude and longitude values - dimensions
    nc_lat <- ncvar_get( nc, attributes(nc$dim)$names[3])
    nc_lon <- ncvar_get( nc, attributes(nc$dim)$names[4])
    nc_time <- ncvar_get( nc, attributes(nc$dim)$names[1])
````

But from here on, I'm quite lost how to actually get this into a useable format, e.g. a raster. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no need to directly use the ncdf4 package like you do (and see several similar questions on this site about that). Normally, you can do `b <- brick(file)`; but I here I use the newer `terra` package

```
 library(terra)
 chl <- rast("filename", "chl")
 pp <- rast("filename", "nppv")
```

From there on you can use, for example, `tapp`. But, if this works, you can perhaps you can edit your question and `show(chl)` so that is easier to see what you are dealing with, and perhaps easier to describe what you want to accomplish. It would also be helpful to share an example file.